# What would happen if someone removed the PATH variable from /etc/environment?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, path, remote

Currently, the best known way we found to add an API key to a remote Ubuntu server was by editing it in as an environment variable in `etc/environment`. The infrastructure docs of the project were unfortunately lost in time.

In the `etc/environment` folder, the `PATH` variable is set that is used system-wide. If someone were to accidentally overwrite this variable when trying to add another environment variable, what would happen? Would the damage be so big that doing so would leave the machine in an non-recoverable state?

Comment: If you still had an open shell you could fix it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If someone were to accidentally overwrite this variable when trying to add another environment variable, what would happen?

You would no longer be able to easily start programs that were installed to unusual locations – you would need to run them using the full path instead.

---

There is always a default PATH value set by several components (by the init system for services, by the login handler for interactive sessions), and although different Linux distros tweak it to their own needs, the default is always suitable for the basic system to boot up and let you log in.

(The only reason to have PATH in /etc/environment in the first place is if you need *additional* directories – e.g. some software installed in /opt or /u1 not through the distro's regular packaging.)

If the global PATH setting is corrupted in some other way but you can manage to log in via SSH or console, you can still run executables through their full path (e.g. `/bin/sudo`). And since environment variables are technically not global but copied per-process, you can set it for just that shell while trying to fix things.

> Would the damage be so big that doing so would leave the machine in an non-recoverable state?

As long as you have physical or KVM access, a Linux system is almost always in recoverable state. Most of the boot process doesn't actually rely on PATH all that much, and there are several ways to interrupt it and get a recovery root shell from which you could edit the file back.